# How can we know if a solution of differential equation is multivalued without solving it?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts, branch-points

For a differential equation, say $q(x)y''(x)+p(x) y'(x)+s(x)=0$, how could we know if its solutions are multivalued without solving it. Could we study the branch points and branch cut by simply observing $q(x)$, $p(x)$ and $s(x)$.

Comment: Assuming a singularity at $x=0$ try the anzats $y(x) = x^{\alpha} h(x)$ and/or $y(x) = x^{\alpha} \log(x) h(x)$ where  $h$ is analytic near $0$ and $h(0) \neq 0$. Do you have any particular example in mind?

Comment: @WimC Airy equation, for instance.

Comment: Did you check Hille's book on holomorphic ODEs ("Ordinary Differential Equations in the Complex Domain")? The general strategy is to transform the equation (by a change of variables) to the one of the form $y''+ \phi(t)y=0$. Then consider singularities of $\phi$, these are the potential branch-points. The theory in the case of regular singular points is reasonably well-understood, I am not sure about the general case.